Exporting labels of vector GPKG to DXF on QGIS 3.34 GUI Windows 10
Objective: Generate a DXF grid of depth labels of a water body in AUTOCAD, a sample is shown here. 
Input: I have a raster from which I have performed "raster pixel to points" to create a vector of points with the z-coordinate as the depth as shown here.  
There are about 50k rows of data in the vector file. The attribute table is shown here. 
Data used: <Vector data GPKG>
Attempts:
I have tried several options in QGIS to generate the DXF and have gone through other Q & A in the forums.

Project> Import/ Export> Export Project to DXF

From the Q & A in the forums, I tried different combinations of Encoding, Symbology mode and scale, ensured correct CRS (UTM), Export labels as MTEXT elements.
I have also tried out different size options in the properties of the vector (millimeters, pixel, map units, points).

I have tried other exporting options:
Plugin: export to DXF
Toolbox options: Export layers to DXF, GRASS v.out.dxf

Output DXFs: The DXFs generated either seem to crash AUTOCAD or just display the marker dot without any labels.
What am I doing incorrectly?

perhaps at the vector generation stage?
Or the exporting configuration stage?

